# How can I change a site's default language after creation (sharepoint 2010)?

Tags: language, multilingual

after creating a site you can go to: 
Site Actions / Site Settings / Site Administration / Language Settings 
and select some alternate language(s) if you've got some language pack(s) installed, but the default one is fix and you can't cange it anymore. Is there a way or some settings.file where you can change the default language?

Answer (score 2):

There is no supported way of changing the language of a site.

Answer (score 1):

Though I am not sure about this, you can play with powershell and try to do this. Look at `SPWeb.UICulture` property and try to set it to some other language and update web.

Also look at this discussion: [How to change the default site language?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30308/how-to-change-the-default-site-language)